# How Can I have an empty version tag in Maven3

Tags: maven-3

I want a dependency to be resolved with no version. Maven 3 is forcing me to use a version, I can't provide a version for the system scope jar I'm resolving. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a system property define as below to resolve dependency.

```xml
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You also have the option to provide [Dependency Version Ranges](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html). You might want to do is something like `<version>[1.2.3,)</version>`

Comment: I know those properties. I was wondering if there's a way to omit the version of a dependency.

Comment: @Sam No. There is not any way for this.