# Is there a way to leave the version tag in the maven pom.xml empty or blank

Tags: maven, war, pom.xml

I'm working on a Maven project in Netbeans 8 and every time that I generate the WAR by clicking the "cleaning and building" option, the WAR generates with the version name that I put in the verion tag. Like this MyProjectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.

Is there a way to leave this version tag empty so when I generate the WAR the name would be just the project name? Like this MyProjectName.war, I'm tired of changing the name of the war so the paths of CSSs in the code could work.

I also tried removing the `version` tag but the pom.xml gives me an error saying that they couldn't find the version tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: How to rename the war file for the project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488509/maven-how-to-rename-the-war-file-for-the-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I have an empty version tag in Maven3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081060/how-can-i-have-an-empty-version-tag-in-maven3)